# how to select particular set of records from all the records

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a query which gives me all records. Now i want to check that out of all records how many records lies between these three conditions

1. Less than and equal to 250,000
2. 250,000 between 500,000
3. 500,000 and above

I am getting total of 6 columns. By subtracting column `Credit Dist dt - App Received dt` i get `working days1`, by subtracting `LO Issued - appr_dec` i get `working days2`. After determining what records lies in which condition, then i have to take count of all applications in each of these conditions and divide the count of application with `working day1` and `working day2`. How can i determine which application lies in which condition and proceed further ?

The query is very long, so i try to put a dummy query to just give an idea.

```
select LOSA_APP.app_ref_no AS "App.Ref.No.",
       LOSA_EXP_SUMM_Z.group_exp AS "Group Exposure Amount",
       column AS "App Received dt",
       column AS "Credit Dist dt",
       column AS "appr_dec",
       column AS "LO Issued" 
from 
    losa_app LOSA_APP
INNER JOIN
    code_branch CODE_BRANCH
ON
    LOSA_APP.attend_branch = CODE_BRANCH.branch_id
.... -- more joins
where
    LOSA_APP.app_status in ('A','R')
and
    .....  --other conditions
```

For condition i have to check against `LOSA_EXP_SUMM_Z.group_exp` like `LOSA_EXP_SUMM_Z.group_exp <= 250,000`, `LOSA_EXP_SUMM_Z.group_exp between 250,000 and 500,000`, `LOSA_EXP_SUMM_Z.group_exp >= 500,000`

Thanks

Comment: You can use SUM(CASE col <= 250000 then 1 else 0 end) you can continue like this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to partition your output by that column/condition, e.g. group 1 - Less than and equal to 250,000, group2..., group 3...  Then you may order it within the group. Try using RANK and other analytic functions.

Select * From
(
    Select empno, deptno, sal 
         , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno Order by sal) rnk
    From scott.emp
)
/

Comment: yes, i have to partition my output in three conditions, because i need all three. I can't use `case` because in case when some condition become true the rest are skip off. I have to encounter one condition and then with respect to it do the calculation.